# Definition of Peak JVM Memory OnHeap on Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ui

I'm under the impression that if I set `spark.executor.memory` to 50G, then [with this formula](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/tuning.html#memory-management-overview) and reading [this article](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/decoding-memory-in-spark-parameters-that-are-often-confused-c11be7488a24)

The maximum heap will be 30.3G. But the peak JVM onHeap I'm seeing in Spark UI is `39.3 GiB`

[image: Spark UI Screenshot]

Can I get some help to explain what is missing from my current understanding?

The values I'm seeing in Spark UI does not match the understanding I got from reading:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/tuning.html#memory-management-overview
- https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/decoding-memory-in-spark-parameters-that-are-often-confused-c11be7488a24

I'm also using this following config
`spark.executor.memoryOverhead=10G`